Remmina 1.4.35 RDP certificate issue
I updated to Remmina 1.4.35 and started having an issue logging in to a Windows computer via RDP; let's call this computer A. I can log in to A from another Windows computer using Windows' Remote Desktop Connection; let's call this computer B. A runs Windows Server 2019 Standard, and B runs Windows 10 Education. When I logged in to B from my Ubuntu 24.04 computer on the apt-version Remmina, I got this error message. This seems like duplicating many similar questions, but I hope to provide below some more clues for debugging.

When I logged in from A to B, I got a warning saying B's certificate is not from a trusted certifying authority, and I needed to accept the certificate error to log in. If I logged in from A and stayed on B, and then I tried logging in from my laptop/Remmina, A would be disconnected with a message saying because another computer just logged in with the same account.
I have tried choosing ignore certificate and all the combinations of security protocols, gateway transport types, and TLS security levels; none solved the problem. I nominally use auto for all the security options, and that usually works except for this certificate-issue computer.
Update:
Thank @user68186 for the reminder. Here is the information:

Disto: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (6.8.0-40-generic)
How I updated Remmina:


sudo add-apt-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade


What's wrong with the original Remmina:
It failed to log in to the computer (B) that I wanted to. I searched and found similar issues and thought this might be it, so I went ahead to try the solutions found online. I first did the update above, not working. Then, I purged the apt-version Remmina and installed a snap version, still not working. I thought B might be physically down, so I logged in A (worked) and then logged in to B from A, where I found the symptom detailed in my original post. I forgot at what point did I remove the snap version (with --purge) to go back to the apt version, so I can't say the symptom applies to snap version, too.


Which distro and version of Linux are you using? How did you update Remmina? What was wrong with the version of Remmina Linux came with? Edit your question and add all these information.

I found a workaround. Using "restricted admin mode" solves it. I am not sure it is the best solution, but it's good enough for me.
